# The rest was off the peg, Smiley decided. Maston was off the peg too, for that matter

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> He once bought a collection of 19th century watercolours, and some of these were hanging on the walls. The rest was **off the peg**, Smiley decided. Maston was **off the peg** too, for that matter. His suit was just too light for respectability; the string of his monocle cut across the invariable cream shirt. He wore a light wollen tie. A German would call him flott, thought Smiley; chic, that's what he is - a barmaid's dream of a real gentleman.

What does *off the peg* mean here? I understand that it means ready-made. Does it mean the same here when referring to Maston? Why would barmaids think of him as chic when his suits is ready-made and lacks respectability? And the sentence "the rest was off the peg" refers to the short piece of wood used for hanging things (i.e. the rest of the paintings were not shown)?

Source: Call for the dead (John Le Carre)

Comment: It's an ironic shift. Off the peg means there were watercolours that were not put  up, that were not hanging off the wall on a peg. Not properly presented for viewing. Then, when he switches and says Maston was off the peg, he means something like: unpresentable. It's sort of a joke, a litote. Very British humoUr. :) One can't help of thinking of: off his head, also. So, it's almost a synecdoche by substitution, as well.

Comment: What a wonderful writer he is.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks! Can you explain a bit more on what makes this British humour?

Comment: Maybe it means two different things.

Comment: It's quite subtle but very funny.  The shift of meaning in a word in the same context is used a lot in comedy or comedic writing, but it's the subtlety of it that makes it funny, where a peg becomes a substitute for a head: off his head is BrE to mean acting sort of crazy. I dunno, its perhaps too "delicate" to be AmE. Just a thought.

Comment: I have a different take on this.  It seems to me "off the peg" means what we'd call in AmE "off the rack" or "mass produced".  Smiley _decides_ some of the water colours are "off the peg".  So is Maston--he suit is too light; he's dashing, snappy, a barmaid's interpretation of a real gentleman.  He's put-together, stylized, not genuine (a spy?)  This all depends on what Carre means by "off the peg."

Comment: I agree with Xanne. "Off the peg" is not referring to the watercolours (if it was then the plural would be used). Everything apart from the watercolours is "off the peg".

Comment: @DJClayworth - The rest of *the collection* is off the peg.  Singular is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: Some of the watercolours were not on  pegs on the wall.  I don't think that the first peg refers to off the rack. That is purely for clothes. Not art. And that would be a mixed metaphor and Le Carré would not do that. Clearly, hanging on the walls (for sale) and the rest off the peg (either not for sale or not on the walls). A plural is not needed.

Comment: @Lambie - Yeah.  I'm guessing that "on/off the peg" is art museum speak for stuff that's on display or not.

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes, or even just his way of saying it.

Comment: @HotLicks On reflection you may be right.

Answer (score 7):

"Off the peg" is a description applied to clothes, especially men's suits, meaning that they are bought from a selection of ready-made styles and sizes, rather than being made to order. "Off the rack" is the North American equivalent.

The implication is that the decor (with the exception of the watercolours) is bought ready-made to fit some standardized look, rather than according to the individual taste of Maston. "The rest" in the second sentence may mean "everything apart from the watercolours" or "the watercolours not on display" (in which case "off the peg" may mean "not hanging on the wall). In any case the subsequent parts imply that Maston himself, his clothes and appearance, have been constructed from 'standard parts' to fit a specific image.

The point about barmaids is that barmaids (in Smiley's view) have a low standard of what they think of as a 'gentlemen'. Anyone in a suit and with a monacle would be considered a gentleman, regardless of whether it was 'off the peg' or not.

Comment: This explanation is so lucid, I'm envious.

Comment: It's worth noting that the *off the peg idiom* was a bit condescending back then. It only worked one way, and off-the-peg clothes were not in everyone's  budget. A lot of clothing was still being made in the home. "New advances in mass production allowed for more garments to be manufactured at greater speed and in greater quantity than ever before. As production speed increased, clothing became more affordable, and off-the-rack manufacturers hurried to copy the designs of haute couture." https://bellatory.com/fashion-industry/Fashion-History-Womens-Clothing-of-the-1950s

Comment: @Phil Sweet Sorry, but I don't think that at the height of the Cold War clothes were still being made at home. That sounds like a pre-World War II world. The Smiley epoch was well past World War II.

Comment: Smiley was definitely not making his own clothes. In fact, frankly, Smiley is a bit of a snob.

Comment: @Lambie The negative economic impact of WWII on Britain lasted a long time. Clothes rationing lasted until 1949, and some kinds of food rationing lasted until 1954. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationing_in_the_United_Kingdom#Timeline

Comment: "Off the peg" is condescending for the opposite reason to Phil Sweet's suggestion. Smiley looks down on Maston because he evidently cannot afford a 'bespoke' suit (made to his own measurements).